How to hide purple outline for users currently viewing a list?
It looks like List views have been updated by Microsoft and now when a user is currently viewing an item, a purple outline appears with the user's name telling the whole world that they're looking at it.

My problem is that my list contains internal job listings. As you can imagine, many users aren't going to want the entire company to know that they may be eyeballing a department change or possible career move unless they decide to pull the trigger and apply.
Is there a way to remove this purple highlighting so that users can view the list items anonymously?

As of now, there isn't a direct setting to disable the purple outline feature for individual lists or views. Microsoft hasn't provided a toggle to turn off this specific feature, so you might not find a setting within the list view settings.
As a desperate measure you can try fixing it with custom SPFx :/
